# How to find the complex solutions of equations substituted to become polynomials?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I came across this problem on the Math Discord.

$\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)^{\log_4{x}}=512$

It was given to a high school student who was only expected to find the 2 real solutions. Figuring that out didn't take very long. What isn't as obvious to me is how to get the <strike>4</strike> complex solutions. There are <strike>6</strike> several solutions altogether, so shouldn't there be a way to restructure it as a <strike>6th-degree</strike> polynomial, or using Euler's Formula?

(UPDATE: I don't understand how this thing has 12 solutions, much less 6. What structure makes it look like it is going to have 12 solutions, besides Wolfram Alpha sometimes finding more numerical solutions?

Here is one of my workings:

Let $x=2^t$. Then

$\left(\frac{2^t}{2^3}\right)^{\log_{2^2}\left({2^t}\right)}=2^9$

$2^{\left(t-3\right)\frac{t}{2}}=2^9$

$\frac{1}{2}t^2 - \frac{3}{2}t - 9 = 0$

$t^2 - 3t - 18 = 0$

$(t+3)(t-6)=0$

and by back-substitution,

$x = 64, x=\frac{1}{8}$

...but again, these are only the 2 real solutions. There should be 6 solutions. What is the way to attack a problem like this that reveals the 6 solutions?

Comment: In fact there are twelve complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)^{\log_4(x)}=512$$

Take logarithms and write
$$\frac{\log (x) (\log (x)-3\log (2))}{2\log (2)}=9\log(2)$$ Let $\log(x)=t$ and you face the problem of finding the complex roots of the function
$$f(x)=\log^2(x)-3\log(2)\,\log(x)-18\log^2(2)=0$$ where $x$ is a complex number.

To visualize, draw the contour plot of
$$\Phi(a,b)=\Re\big[f(a+ib)\Big]^2+\Im\big[f(a+ib)\Big]^2$$

There are (at least) twelve explicit solutions (a bit long to write). Numerically, they are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -214.440715101 \, \pm \, 27.7655058009 \, i \\
 -84.8332243277 \, \pm \, 102.744557701 \, i \\
 -0.03822797296 \, \pm \, 0.04629926782 \, i \\
 -0.03669122954 \, \pm \, 0.00475073284 \, i \\
 +0.02678575770 \, \pm \, 0.09295439011 \, i \\
 +22.8987140031 \, \pm \, 79.4652150001 \, i 
\end{array}
\right)$$

I give you the explicis solution for the first one
$$x=2 \sqrt{2}\,\exp\Bigg[\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2} \log (2) \left(\sqrt{256 \pi ^2+729 \log ^2(2)}+27
   \log (2)\right)}\pm $$ $$\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2} \log (2) \left(\sqrt{256 \pi
   ^2+729 \log ^2(2)}-27 \log (2)\right)} \Bigg]$$